# Text Indent -9999px.. not working at all

Tags: html, css

I am using a background image to replace the text of a link using text-indent: -9999px;

Anyone have any clue why this isnt working in this instance. You will see the top right logo is displaying the text and logo.. although I am telling it not to..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `<a>` tag is aligned right.

Set `text-align:left;` on that link and it should work as you expect.